# Javascript array/object syntax fail

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, object-literal

Why do I get this error with this code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on line 1.

```
var cube_points = {
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100}
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your outer object's elements have values but no keys. If you want an array of cube points, use the square bracket to denote an array literal:

```
var cube_points = [
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100}
];
```

If you want an object, give the items a key. This could be numbers or letters or even objects:

```
var cube_points = {
    1: {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    2: {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    'q': {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    'z': {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    '25': {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100},
    '26': {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    10: {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    11: {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100}
};
```

Obviously, using an object necessitates some kind of orderly system of key selection. Since your points aren't easily named, you're better off using an array. But I wanted to show what object literal notation would look like.

Comment: I honestly think starting at `0` in the object is more consistent.

Comment: It's an object. You can use letters or numbers or objects as keys. But just to put a lid on the critics, I'll make some adjustments.

Answer (score 7):

What you have is not a valid javascript object definition. `{}` denotes object, so inside you should have properties, not other `{}`. What you need is an array which is denoted with `[]`:

```
var cube_points = [
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : 100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100},
    {'x' : 100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : -100},
    {'x' : -100, 'y' : -100, 'z' : 100}
];
```

which you could then access like this:

```
cube_points[2].y
```